# unmarshall aggregate result with Jongo

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo, mongo-jackson-mapper

I am using the MongoDB aggregate framework to query a document, the results is the following:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "luke",
                        "times" : 8
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "albert",
                        "times" : 4
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "matt",
                        "times" : 4
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

As you can see from the result above, the query works in the mongoDB shell, but I have a problem when getting the results with Jongo:

```
        Aggregationoutput = 
                gamesCollection.aggregate(
                "{ ... }"
                ).as(Aggregation.class);
        output.results().iterator().hasNext();
```

The main problem seems to be that Jongo doesn't allow me to use `AggregationOutput`? he wants instead `Aggregation` ... but can't find any example available on how to use it

**EDIT:**
I am a bit frustrated that I can't make Jongo to work with the aggregate. I had to write the query with `DBObjects` as specified in the MongoDB Java driver, but the code looks really ugly..

**EDIT2:**
Just to complete the information, this is the original aggregate I was using with Jongo which could not unmarshall to ResultObject

```
List<ResultObject> output = 
                gamesCollection.aggregate(
                "{ $match: { 'playersList.playerid': 'bob' }},"
                +"{ $unwind: '$playersList' },"
                +"{ $match: { 'playersList.playerid':  { $ne: 'bob' } } },"
                +"{ $group: { _id: '$playersList.playerid', times: { $sum : 1} } },"
                +"{ $sort: { times: -1 } }"
                ).as(ResultObject.class);

class ResultObject{
  String _id;
  int times;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please share the code of the Aggregation class and the complete collection.aggregate(..) that you're querying with Jongo? Thanks.

Comment: I'll go for the quick and dirty solution, when I got time I'll go back and revise your suggestions. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: As you wish. It seems to me that with your complete code, we can solve this in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use aggregate feature like find/findOne... Results are automatically unmarshalled into  Pojo :

```
List<Email> emails = collection.aggregate("{$project:{sender:1}}")
          .and("{$match:{tags:'read'}}")
          .and("{$limit:10}")
          .as(Email.class);
```

You can find more examples here : https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jongo/AggregateTest.java

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this question now, but I hope it can help others.
You can create an inner class like this:

```
private static class AggregateResult {
        String _id;
        int time;
    }
```

And call the aggregate function as following:

```
List<AggregateResult> res =  gamesCollection.aggregate(
                "{ ... }"
                ).as(AggregateResult.class);
```

Then you can iterate over the results in the res list.